# Change Sharepoint task parent id via REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, jsom, project-server, odata

I'm trying to move a subtask from one parent to another. I could change the tasks name with such a PATCH query:

```
PATCH /sites/PWA/_api/ProjectServer/Projects('4b951130-e0b9-e911-910f-001dd8b71c8d')/Draft/Tasks('af5369a8-e0b9-e911-910f-001dd8b71c8d') HTTP/1.1
Host: [host]
Accept: application/json
X-RequestDigest: [digest]
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Basic cG93ZAJtXFNpbWFcaW5fRFY6U2ltMHkxMjE3
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.15.2
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 87937c7f-b10f-4537-9a87-957376a53f01,5535333f-4059-4d79-a335-6b4cb1739896
Host: [host]
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 56
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache

{
    "Name":"NewName"
}
```

It worked, but when I am trying to change the parent id:

```
{
    "Name":"NewName",
    "ParentId":"5b5369a8-e0b9-e911-910f-001dd8b71c8d"
}
```

Only the name changes, it seems that it just ignores the `ParentId`, but when creating, not updating a subtask with the `ParentId` parameter everything worked fine.

What is wrong with my query?
Why does it allow to create a task with parent id and does not update it?

PS.
I've also tried to use `ParentIDId` instead of `ParentId`, but it worked neither.

Also, tried to pass this id instead of guid to `ParentIDId`, but again, only the name has changed:
[image]

```
{
    "Name":"NewName",
    "ParentIDId":"5"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried passing Item Id of Main/Parent task in you Post/Update query like: `{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.TaskListItem'}, 'Title': 'Subtask Title', 'ParentIDId':ParentTaskItemId }`. Where `ParentTaskItemId` is list item id of main/parent task.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you just missed a comma in the JSON between fields:

```
{
    "Name":"NewName",
    "ParentId":"5b5369a8-e0b9-e911-910f-001dd8b71c8d"
}
```

Also, as far as I remember the ParentID is a lookup field, so the body should be like this:

```
{
    "Name":"NewName",
    "ParentIDId":5 
}
```

Where 5 is an ID of the new parent.

Comment: Oops, I've missed the comma just in the question, the syntax of the actual request was correct.

Comment: I've tried to pass id from list instead of guid, but again only the name changes. By the way, I've passed guid to `ParentId` when creating the subtask and it worked fine.